# CTE Joins in Hadoop zero rows

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql, common-table-expression

When I run a CTE join in Hadoop, it results in 0 rows.

```
WITH 

cte1 as 
(
    SELECT 
        product_segment,
        'a' as AT
    FROM t1
    WHERE data_type = 'v1'
),


cte2 as 
(
    SELECT 'a' as AT
    FROM t1
    WHERE data_type = 'v2'
)


SELECT a.product_segment
FROM cte1 a 
INNER JOIN cte2 b ON (a.AT = b.AT)
```

I know that t1 has a bunch of data, and that the CTEs splits the table into 2 based on a dimension. There's a bunch of overlap. Even when I use a LEFT JOIN it comes back with zero rows.

Can you join CTEs in Hadoop?

Comment: I imagine that one or both CTEs are empty.

Comment: Definitely not empty. Tested it multiple times

Comment: Does Hadoop support recursive queries???

Comment: Check counts `WHERE data_type = 'v2' `and also `WHERE data_type = 'v1'`

Comment: Turns out Hadoop doesn't like many to many joins. Once I got unique values it worked